# Native code exiting without error - probably memory

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a thread that calls a `main` function in c native code.

This does not return to java, so I have to be careful with memory allocations.

The main function calls a static method on java as a way of a call back. Here is how that is achieved in c:

```
void writeat(int x, int y, int style, char *string) {
    JNIEnv *env = getJNIEnv();
    static jmethodID cls_mid = NULL;

    if (cls_mid == NULL) {
        jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/comp/prod/Kernel");
        cls_mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, clazz, "writeat",
                "(IIILjava/lang/String;)V");
    }

    {
        jstring out = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, string);
        (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, nullVoid, cls_mid, x, y, style,
                out);
        (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, out);
    }
}
```

This works for a short while, then dies without any error logged in log cat.

If I comment out the `CallStaticVoidMethod` call, it still does the same. If I comment out the new and delete calls, it does not have the problem.

This is called many hundreds of times a second just with the string "000", so that is why it quickly runs out of memory I think.

Any help on getting info on diognosing the error would be great, as at this point I just see nothing in the log cat.

**Update: My old main and getJNIEnv**

```
 JNIEnv *_env;

 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_comp_prod_main(JNIEnv *env,
        jclass thiz) {
    LOGV("Main called %d", __LINE__);
    _env = (JNIEnv *) ((*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, env));
      main();
    _env = NULL;
  }

  JNIEnv *getJNIEnv(void) {
     return _env;
  }
```

**My new main and getJNIEnv**

```
JavaVM *jvm;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_comp_prod_main(JNIEnv *env,
        jclass thiz) {
    LOGV("Main called %d", __LINE__);
    //this is how to cache it for other threads
    jint rs = (*env)->GetJavaVM(env, &jvm);
    assert (rs == JNI_OK);
    main();
    jvm = NULL;
}

JNIEnv *getJNIEnv(void) {
    JNIEnv *env;
     jint rs = (*jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(jvm, &env, NULL);
     assert (rs == JNI_OK);
     if(env == NULL)
     {
       LOGV("env is NULL");
     }
     return env;
}
```

Call from Java:

```
Runnable runTerm = new Runnable() {

public void run() {
  // call main()
  Log.i(TAG, "About to call main on the c!");
  try {
    Terminal.main();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
};

t = new Thread(runTerm, "C thread");
t.start();
```

Comment: The presented code looks correct. Some thoughts: 1. check `string!=NULL` before calling `NewString`. 2. check `out!=NULL` before calling `VoidMethod`. 3. make sure that `string` is not mutated by some other thread while `writeat` is running. It should be `const char*` for a reason. 4. (slightly unrelated) If you really call this hundreds times per second, consider caching `clazz` and `cls_mid`. I suppose that you do `AttachCurrentThread` in getJNIEnv().

Comment: 4. I do, `cls_mid` is `static`.

Comment: Will check other points, thanks, I will also post `getJNIEnv` later.

Comment: @PavelZdenek Point 3. Doesn't `NewStringUTF` take a copy? If not, am I better off making a local c copy using `strdup` then `free`?

Comment: 4. ok, now i understand `if (cls_mid == NULL)` being a lazy init. 3. yes `NewStringUTF` is making a copy, but shit can still happen WHILE it is making this copy. By the way, are you sure that it's the JNI calls making a problem? Did you review the code which calls `writeat()`? Is it calling with the same preallocated char buffer, or are you re-creating for each call?

Comment: @PavelZdenek Pretty sure I have fixed it by correcting mycode in `getJNIEnv` please see update. The comment on "I suppose that you do AttachCurrentThread in getJNIEnv()" helped, so if you want to put that in an answer I'll accept. If you can explain what was wrong I'd be even happier as still confused, as far as I am concerned all this takes place in one thread `main()` never returns and all `writeat` calls are from there.

Comment: So your Java calls some JNI `main` and this main fires off a native thread which then eventually calls `writeat`? This is a scenario in which your original code *won't* work, so i need to have it confirmed.

Comment: @PavelZdenek Not quite, Java starts the thread, the `c` code is all single threaded.

Comment: @PavelZdenek see edit for java call

Comment: Ok so writeat is somehow called from `runTerm` (in its `run()` method) ? I am still confused by your statement that "*c code is all single threaded*"

Comment: @PavelZdenek Yes runterm calls main, which calls writeat.  main is blocking. so all the native code runs in this thread which is what I meant by single threaded

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19673/discussion-between-pavel-zdenek-and-weston)

Answer (score -1):

You aren't releasing the string when you're done with it, so you're leaking it every call.

Comment: If you mean the `char *string` parameter, it's passed in to the function, it's a pointer to static or stack memory, never `malloc`ed memory. If you mean something else, please elaborate.

Comment: jstring out-  you create it via NewStringUTF, but you never release the string.  This is a leak.  You need to call ReleaseStringUTFChars

Comment: That's crashing worse now - Isn't `ReleaseStringUTFChars` for cleaning up `GetStringUTFChars` java string->native string. This is native string->java string

Comment: Indeed `ReleaseString` is only for `GetString`, in java->native scenario. In case of native->java, you are responsible yourself for the management of underlying char*.